# Asus R510D with Windows 8: Want to change volume with one button, rather than fn+F10/F11/F12

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, asus-laptop, fn-key

I have a new Asus laptop (R510D-FH11), and I would like to change the volume with one keystroke. As it is, I have to hold down fn+F10 or fn+F11. Because of my keyboard layout and average-sized female palms/fingers this requires two hands.

How can I change the keyboard settings to single-key commands? I don't mind switching F11 to fn+F11 to make a browser fullscreen. Some threads have mentioned making changes in the BIOS, but I can't find them on this computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it can't be done unless a there's a BIOS update released by your PC manufacturer for your notebook that lets you use the F1-F12 keys as "hotkeys" (you don't press Fn to access secondary function)

*However*, if you don't mind re-mapping certain keys on your keyboard that you don't use too often, then you could use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a remap script that maps a key on yout keyboard to another.

I tried this script on my notebook and it worked well. It **might** work for you as well:

Start Notepad and enter the following lines of code into it and save it as `VolumeControl.ahk`

```
F1::Volume_Mute
F2::Volume_Down
F3::Volume_Up
```

Download and install AutoHotkey. Then double click on the newly created `AHK` script and now whenever you press buttons F1 through F3, your computer's sound volume should mute, decrease and increase respectively

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! I'm also excited to use AutoHotkey for other things.